# Open video file in C#

Tags: c#, file

I am new to C# and this might sound stupid, I did some research and I think I am confused.
I want my c# program to open a video file (c:\abc.mov), I have set the .mov files to open automatically with quick time player and I want the program to open the file with quick time player just like double clicking on that file. 
When I use this code it does not do anything!

```
File.Open(@"c:\abc.mov", FileMode.Open);
```

Please help me?

Comment: Do you mean you want to play the video? (Open it means so very little.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Process.Start` instead. Here's the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) on that.

You can specify which program you want to start with whetever arguments you need, [like in this example.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start)

**Edit:** Added another example. Thanks @DJBurb

```
Process.Start(@"c:\\abc.mov");
```

This code should open the `.mov` file with the default movie player associated with the `.mov` extension.

Comment: Process.Start(@"c:\\abc.mov") should automatically open the file in the program that the extension is associated with

Comment: Thanks so much, it is working now, I have to figure out how to automatically start the video and make it full screen now!

Answer (score 1):

This will open your video file with the dafault video player

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that open() will open your file for editing for this current program, not actually opening the file with your system's default player

Answer (score 0):

`File.Open` returns `FileStream` so you can read that file, instead you most definitely want to use `Process.Start(@"c:\abc.mov");`

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Process.Start(ofd.FileName);
        }
    }
```